# How to make a fixed div based in parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-float

Below is my design:

```
<html xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="head">
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="items">
                <ul>
                    <li>Item1</li>
                    <li>Item2</li>
                    <li>Item3</li>
                    <li>Item4</li>
                    <li>Item5</li>
                    .....
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="items-footer">
                <input type="text"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a header, body and footer. In Body I have few items to show and beneath that items there is items footer which contains textbox to add dynamic items in that list. My requirement is how can I make fixed div which will remain at the bottom (just above the footer) when user is scrolling the items. I want "items-footer" to be always displayed in the view port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Description

You don't need `javascript` for that, you can do this in pure `css` using `position:fixed` and `bottom:0px`.

Check out my sample and this [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/DX6fM/)

#### Sample

```
#items-footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;  
}
```

#### More Information

- [W3C - CSS/Properties/bottom](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/bottom)
- [W3C - CSS/Properties/position](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/position)

Comment: But in this case the floating div comes above the footer too. http://jsfiddle.net/DX6fM/1/

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the div items a fixed height, with `overflow:auto` in CSS. That will enable scrolling when the content in the div becomes larger than the div itself. 
so you will scroll through your list but all other divs stay in place except for the children of items.